# Converting String to Binary Hash Tree

Tags: c++, tree

I've written a pretty basic algorithm to convert a string to a binary hash tree of its characters, where each character represents a leaf node. The hash tree itself is being stored in a vector.

If the number of leaf nodes is not a power of 2, I'm padding the number leaf nodes with empty substrings until the number of leaves is a power of 2.

I know there's likely a much better way to achieve this, but I'm having trouble picturing what that would look like. What are some alternate, potentially more performant approaches I may have overlooked?

Please disregard the chosen hash function (DJB2()).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include "../code/hash.h"

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    unsigned int hash;
};

bool IsPowerOfTwo(int c) {
    int a = ceil(log2(c));
    int b = floor(log2(c));

    return a == b;
}

int NextPowerOfTwo(int c) {
    int a = ceil(log2(c));

    return pow(2, a);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    string str = "abc34";

    vector<shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;

    int leaves = IsPowerOfTwo(str.length()) ? str.length() : NextPowerOfTwo(str.length());

    int total_nodes = 2 * leaves - 1;

    int non_leaves = total_nodes - leaves;

    // Add root + internal nodes to vector
    for(int i = 0; i < non_leaves; i++) {
        shared_ptr<Node> new_node(new Node);
        nodes.push_back(new_node);
    }

    // Generate the hash for leaf nodes + add to vector
    for (int i = 0; i < leaves; i++) {
        shared_ptr<Node> new_node(new Node);

        string substr = (i >= str.length()) ? "" : string (1, str[i]);

        new_node->hash = DJB2(substr);

        nodes.push_back(new_node);
    }

    // Generate the hash for internal and root nodes
    for (int i = non_leaves - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        int left_child_index = 2 * i + 1;

        int right_child_index = 2 * i + 2;

        string left_child_hash = to_string(nodes[left_child_index]->hash);

        string right_child_hash = to_string(nodes[right_child_index]->hash);

        string child_hashes = left_child_hash + right_child_hash;

        nodes[i]->hash = DJB2(child_hashes);
    }

    // Output index of node in vector/tree and its corresponding hash value
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        cout << i << " : " << nodes[i]->hash << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Defnitely more suited here ;) +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use the C++ version of standard C header files

You are including `<math.h>`, but you should include `<cmath>`. Especially for the math functions, using the versions from `std::` will make sure they automatically deduce whether they should return `float` or `double`.

## Avoid unnecessary use of floating point arithmetic

Converting an integer to floating point, doing some operation, and then converting back is going to be slow. Floating point math is also not always exact, and this can cause problems if you assume it is. If possible, do everything using integer arithmetic where possible.

To see what you can do with just integers, look at Sean Eron Anderson's [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html), it includes how to [check if an integer is a power of two](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) and how to [round up to the next power of two](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2).

Even better, if you can use C++20, use [`std::has_single_bit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit) to check if something is a power of two, and [`std::bit_ceil()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_ceil) to round up to the nearest power of two.

## Unnecessary use of `std::shared_ptr`

I don't see any reason to use `std::shared_ptr` for storing `Node`s. You should be able to just write:

```
…
int non_leaves = total_nodes - leaves;
std::vector<Node> nodes(non_leaves);
```

This creates a vector of `non_leaves` `Node`s. Then to add the leaf nodes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < leaves; ++i) {
    std::string substr = (i >= str.length()) ? "" : std::string(1, str[i]);
    nodes.emplace_back(DJB2(substr));
}
```

In the rest of the code, you can replace `->hash` with `.hash, since the elements of` nodes` are no longer pointers.

## Use `.reserve()`

Since STL containers do not know up front how many elements you are going to place in them, they start out small and allocate more memory later, and for `std::vector` is also has to move elements from the old to the new memory region each time it grows. But if you know up front how many elements you are going to store, you can call `.reserve()` so it can do one big allocation up front:

```
std::vector<Node> nodes(…);
nodes.reserve(total_nodes);
```

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer to use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the are mostly equivalent, but the latter also forces the output to be flushed, which is often unnecessary and can be bad for performance.

## Suboptimal calculation of internal node hash values

Regardless of the performance of `DJB2()` itself, one issue is that for the internal nodes, you are converting indices to strings, concatenating those strings, and then hashing the result of that. That is not efficient, and it also has some issues. For example, consider these scenarios:

- `left_child_hash = "123"; right_child_hash = "45";
- `left_child_hash = "12"; right_child_hash = "345";

The child hashes in the second case are clearly different from the first case, but the concatenation is the same. While hash functions don't guarantee uniqueness, so it's probably not a big problem, you are actually providing less information to the hash function than you could, so it's going to perform slightly worse.

One solution would be to do a bitwise copy of the integers into a `std::string` and hash that. Making use of the fact that the two child hash values are already consecutive inside `nodes`:

```
std::string child_hashes(2 * sizeof(Node));

for (int i = non_leaves - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&nodes[2 * i + 1]), 2 * sizeof(Node), child_hashes.data());
    nodes[i].hash = DJB2(child_hashes);
}
```

## Make use of `std::string_view` if possible

It would be nice if `DJB2()` would take a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) as an argument. This would avoid some copies that your code is currently making, like `substr`, and even the `std::copy_n()` into `child_hashes` in the example above.

## Pre-compute commonly used hash values

While the compiler might be able to optimize this for you if it can inline `DJB2()`, you can help it yourself by pre-computing the hash of the empty string:

```
Node empty_node{DJB2("")};

for (int i = 0; i < leaves; ++i) {
    if (i >= str.length()) {
        nodes.push_back(empty_node);
    } else {
        nodes.emplace_back(DJB2(str.substr(i, 1)));
    }
}
```

Or even better, remove the `if` entirely and just loop up to `str.length()` and pad the vector afterwards:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    nodes.emplace_back(DJB2(str.substr(i, 1)));
}

nodes.insert(nodes.back(), leaves - str.length(), DJB2(""));
```

Also note that if `str` is very large, you will likely calculate the hash of the same character multiple times. You could then speed up this part by pre-computing all possible hashes of a `char`, or by creating a simple cache.